# Detectar si un arreglo esta vacio en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Soy nuevo en angular, espero y me puedan ayudar.
Estoy haciendo una webapp en angular, tengo el siguiente codigo que me llama a una api y returna los valores.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ɵEMPTY_ARRAY } from '@angular/core';
import { Recientes } from './Recientes';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inicio',
  templateUrl: './inicio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inicio.component.css']
})
 
export class InicioComponent implements OnInit {

  isVisible:boolean;
  public recientes:Recientes[];
  count:Int16Array;
  aux:string[];

  constructor(private apiService:ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isVisible=false;
    this.apiService.getTendencias_10().subscribe(
      e=>this.tendencias=e
    );
    this.apiService.getMejorCalificados_10().subscribe(
      e=>this.mejor_calificados=e
    );
    this.apiService.getRecientes().subscribe(
      e=>{
        this.recientes=e;
        if (!!this.recientes.length) {
          this.isVisible=true;
        }
        else {
          this.isVisible=true;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

El problema es que quiero que cuando no devuelva valores la api, la variable **isVisible** pase a false, y viceversa.
He intentado con el *.length* pero no funciona me marca:
`ERROR TypeError: _this.recientes is null` 
Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: `!!array.length` <- esto te debuelve un boolean, `true` si tiene un item el array o `false` si esta vacio, `Boolean(array.length)` <- esto es lo mismo que lo anterior

Comment: Con eso me sale: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Array -> Array -> Array]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Array!

Comment: Puedes manejar la respuesta de la api con la libreria de [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#find), tiene los metodos de isEmpty(), isArray(), isNull(), entre otros que te ayudaran bastante.

Answer (score 0):

El problema probablemente sea que cuando te subscribes a `getRecientes` lo que viene como respuesta `e` no sea una arreglo, haz un console.log para ver lo que viene en la respuesta de `getRecientes`

Comment: Me sale un null simplemente

Comment: Entonces el problema es tu api...

Answer (score 0):

Usa el [encademiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Encadenamiento_opcional) (?.) para evitar errores si `this.recientes` es `null`.

```
 if (this.recientes?.length) {
       this.isVisible = true;
 }
 else {
       this.isVisible = false;
 }
```